# Help interpreting fdisk after boot problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, fdisk

I duelboot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on my laptop (unfortunately I can't remember which version of ubuntu I have). I today tried to boot it up and received the message "error: no such partition" when trying to load either os from grub. After rebooting again I couldn't even get to grub.

I am following [this](http://itsfoss.com/solve-error-partition-grub-rescue-ubuntu-linux/) guide which as far as I can tell is my best bet. However I can't interpret the info I'm getting from fdisk.

```
Device    Boot Start End     Blocks  Id System  
/dev/sda1   *  0     2039807 1019904 0  Empty  
/dev/sda2      20644 25315   2336    ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda1'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

I'm not sure what these two mean. Is ubuntu sda2? Why is one listed as empty? Is the tutorial going to help or do I have different problems? Just need some guidance really. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That looks like the contents of an Ubuntu `.iso` file written to a USB flash drive. It's likely that your hard disk is something else, or perhaps isn't being detected at all because of hardware problems or a missing driver.

Comment: Thank you! Upon further investigetion it seems that my hard drive has failed without warning and can't be saved. So it makes sense that its only finding the iso. Other programs can locate the HDD but can't write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your HDD uses GTP which is useful if the HDD is bigger than 2 TiB. Use GParted instead of `fdisk -l`. It will provide the same information.

Comment: Thank you. GParted has provided some better info which should help me find my specific problem.  

for those interested:  

/dev/sda contains GTP signatures,indicating that it has a GPT table. However, it does not have a valid fake msdow partition table, as it should. perhaps it was corrupted - possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables...